# How to use facebook connect with cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook connect with my cakephp application. i am not sure how facebook conenct works. can some one guide me over this. or provide me links to some tutorial.

is there particular fields that you should have to get the facebook connect to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use new auth system try this:

http://daily.siebler.eu/2010/12/integrating-facebook-connect-open-graph-api-into-cakephp/

or if you prefer using a plugin

www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/223/CakePHP_Configuration_Plugin

Answer (score 2):

A quick google threw up a few links,

http://cutfromthenorth.com/integrating-facebook-connect-with-cakephps-auth-component/
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=27249

Unfortunatly, some of these are blocked for me at work, but hopefully they'll be handy. It does seem that integrating it by extending the Auth compontent would make the most sense.